# How do create .meta file from .flv file?

Tags: flv, red5, streaming-flv-video

I installed red5 server is used for playback video.

As oflademo page, I see each file .flv has a file .meta to playback video, i.e .meta file help pause, play, quick roll video to next step ... Now, I uploaded new file .flv to /usr/local/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/ to playback. And I want to create a similar .meta file.

How do create .meta file from .flv file ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tool in their wiki?

http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Tools/MetadataGenerator